# Netbeans, is there a way to expand tab to spaces on existing files?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I'm using the last version of NetBeans and I would like to know if there is a feature (or a plugin) that converts the tabs into spaces on existing files without changing anything else.

Answer (score 3):

If you have automatic tab expansion enabled [0], then performing a `Source` -> `Format` will convert all tabs to spaces. Keep in mind that will also apply any other options found in that dialog, such as adding/removing blank lines or spaces and changing the position of curly brackets.

[0] it is by default, in `Options` -> `Editor` -> `Formatting`, check the `Expand Tabs To Spaces` box

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately I'm searching for a way to ONLY convert the tabs to spaces without touching anything else.

Comment: In addition to that, it seems to only convert tabs at the beginning of a line. When the tab is somewhere in the middle of a line, it won't be converted.

Answer (score 2):

It's a hack, but you can use search and replace.

1. Ctrl-H, Open the search/replace dialog
2. Toggle the small cog button to enable search by regex (It's just to the right of the 'Match case' and 'Whole word' toggles)
3. Enter \t in the 'Find What' input
4. Using the space bar, enter four spaces in the 'Replace With' input
5. Test using the Next button at least a few times :-)